# Puppeteer with Crawlera Proxy

Tags: puppeteer

I am not able to make a puppeteer request through a proxy that has authentication.

Have tried both proxy url authentication: `--proxy-server=u:p@proxy.crawlera.com:8010`

And also the puppeteer `page.authenticate(u,p)`

still getting `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--proxy-server=proxy.crawlera.com:8010']
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Proxy-Authorization':
      'Basic ' +
      Buffer.from(`${process.env.CRAWLERA_APIKEY}:`).toString('base64')
  });

  page.on('console', (...args) => console.log('PAGE LOG:', ...args));
  const path = `https://www.andersonassociates.net/`;
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1680, height: 895 });

  try {
    console.log('before-goto', path);
    var start = +new Date();
    var resp = await page.goto(path, {
      timeout: 0,
      waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    });

    console.log('after-goto', path);
    var end = +new Date();
    console.log('start-end-diff', (end - start) / 1000);

    if (!resp.ok) {
      browser.close();
      return { status: resp.status, error: `ASIN NOT OK. ${resp.status}` };
    }
    console.log('goto', path);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('page.goto ERROR', error.stack.split('\n'));
    browser.close();
    return { error: error.toString(), stack: error.stack.split('\n') };
  }

  try {
    await page.screenshot({ path: `tmp/anderson.png`, fullPage: true });
    console.log('screenshot');
    browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    browser.close();
    console.log('screenshot error', e.stack.split('\n'));
  }
})();
```

Update!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used Crawlera as my proxy service too, already used proxy-chain & `page.authenticate` method, but no luck, I think it is caused Crawlera provides an empty password, and I solved by using `page.setExtraHTTPHeaders`:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, // To allow https url
    args: ['--proxy-server=proxy.crawlera.com:8010']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('<APIKEY>:').toString('base64'),
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [proxy-chain](https://github.com/Apifier/proxy-chain) npm package for it.

Example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

(async() => {
    const oldProxyUrl = 'http://u:p@proxy.crawlera.com:8010';
    const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

    // Prints something like "http://127.0.0.1:45678"
    console.log(newProxyUrl);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [`--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`],
    });

})();
```

You can read more about it in [blogpost](https://blog.apify.com/how-to-make-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-use-a-proxy-server-with-authentication-249a21a79212).

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the code samples of what you're doing?

Bear in mind that page.authenticate requires an object to be passed to the function. And the credentials have to be setup before doing anything else.

You could try something like this:

```
await page.authenticate({username, password});
await page.goto(myURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000220800-using-crawlera-with-puppeteer) I read about how to setup Crawlera as the proxy provider with Puppeteer.

The blog post states:

> ⚠️  Note: Puppeteer 1.17 and bundled Chromium 76.0.3803.0 are recommended. The latest Chromium snapshot that can be used with Puppeteer 1.18+ is r669921 (in later versions Proxy-Authorization header, required for sending Crawlera credentials, is blocked).

So in order to deploy the solution with Docker that meant [to setup for pupeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker) I needed to download a specific version of Chromium, and Puppeteer doesn't guarantee it will work.

The solution was to use [proxy-chain](https://github.com/apifytech/proxy-chain) and `anonymizeProxy` method and set `ignoreHTTPSErrors: true` when launching the browser